# Как удается работать некоторым классам, вроде LinearLayout, если в их коде так много красных строк?

Tags: android

Как в таких условиях код умудряется работать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

За интерес попробовал отключится от Интернета. К моему удивлению, опять таки код сработал. В смысле программа запустилась на моем Андроид телефоне.

Также интересно, как можно изучать подобные коды, чтобы понять как они работают?

Дополнительно: Я новичок в Android программировании, если что.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходники, которые поставляются с SDK, неполные. Поэтому и высвечивается куча проблем.
Но они предназначены только для быстрого ознакомления и в сборке приложения никак не участвуют.
На устройстве есть собственная, скомпилированная и оптимизированная версия всех классов, соответствующих версии системы устройства.
Именно их и использует приложение во время выполнения.

Теоретически собрать рабочее приложение можно зная только имена классов, методов и полей без реальных классов и их содержимого. Если вы найдёте в SDK android.jar, который использует IDE, и декомпилируете - то там нет кода, все методы пустые, либо только бросают исключение.

Ели вам не достаточно исходников из SDK - вы можете изучать код в репозитории https://source.android.com/ и https://github.com/aosp-mirror через браузер или склонировать на диск.

Comment: По пунктам 1) говоря "на устройстве есть ..." - имеете ввиду настоящий андроид телефон и симуляторы устройств в IDE?  2) "Исходники SDK - неполные и не участвуют в сборке приложения" - имеете ввиду, что SDK сам по себе почти, что бессмысленный? Тогда в чем смысл обновлении, которые требует IDE?  А также получается, что IDE полностью полагается на наличие классов именно в системе реального андроид телефона/симулятора? 3) Последний вопрос - в настоящем устройстве/симуляторе хранятся все классы не только той версии Андроид на котором, работает телефон но также и предыдущих версии?

Comment: Последний вопрос задал исходя из того, что на реальном устройстве могут работать не только те приложения чьи версии совпадают с версией андроид устройства, но также и более старые версии.

Comment: 1) любое устройство, железное или виртуальное, выполняющее Андроид-приложения. 2) В SDK куча инструментов, которые помогают писать, проверять и собирать ваш код в приложение, исходники фреймворка в этом не играют никакой роли. IDE полагается на наборы классов всех версий системы от minSdkVersion до targetSdkVersion, которые вы указываете в build.gradle или манифесте и проверяет код на совместимость со всеми версиями - поэтому приложения работают на разных версиях оси.

Comment: 3) Также и сами версии разрабатываются, по возможности,  максимально совместимыми с предыдущими версиями. Плюс в этом помогают библиотеки поддержки (ныне AndroidX).

Comment: @RubenKubalyan клиентское приложение не содержит в себе скомпилированных классов из API Android, они содержатся на самом устройстве, именно поэтому вы не можете запустить приложение, написанное для android 6, например на устройстве с android 4. Исходники API Android никаким образом не участвуют в компиляции клиентского приложения, ОС на устройстве содержит уже скомпилированные классы из API, соответствующие версии андроид устройства. более новые версии API андроид сохраняют обратную совместимость и приложение для android 4 будет работать и на android 6, более новые API дополняют старые